# Find date and time in filename

Tags: bash, date, time, find

How to extract the date and time from a filename string with different length:

**Example**

```
filename_a=398MUENS05_0_20150409_210733_947.wav
filename_b=346LAUNS01B_20150611_225604.wav
```

I thought about to use the two underscore as marker, but I'm not sure how to do that with bash. I tried to use `cut -d_ -f...` but it won't work as the number of underscores variates in each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with grep like

```
 grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{8\}_[[:digit:]]\{6\}'
```

to find 8 digits followed by underscore then 6 more digits, and get only those parts of the result.  For example:

```
$ filename_a=398MUENS05_0_20150409_210733_947.wav
$ filename_b=346LAUNS01B_20150611_225604.wav
$ echo $filename_a | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{8\}_[[:digit:]]\{6\}'
20150409_210733
$ echo $filename_b | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{8\}_[[:digit:]]\{6\}'
20150611_225604
```